# UIMA ruta annotate a sequence of fixed length containing words from specific wordlist

Tags: uima, ruta

I have a WORDTABLE containing numbers expressed as strings (zero, one, two, ..., *n*) plus the respective digits as features. I am trying to annotate a sequence of a fixed length of stringified numbers.

E.g.:

one two three four -> should be annotated

one two three four five six -> should not be annotated

So far I have done

```
WORDTABLE numbers = "numbers.csv";

DECLARE Annotation number(STRING int_string, STRING digit);
DECLARE Annotation numberSequence;

Document{-> MARKTABLE(number, 1, numbers, "digit" = 2)};
(number number) {-> MARK(numberSequence)};
```

This matches a sequence containing *n* stringified number, what I want is establishing the length of the sequence, something like:

```
number[4,4] {-> MARK(numberSequence)};
```

where the minimum and maximum tokens in the sentence containing the stringified numbers should be equal, for example, to 4.
Is it possible to do this?

Comment: How you tried to apply the last rule? You maybe wnat to extend it in order to avoid matches in longer sequences: `ANY{-PARTOF(number)} @number[4,4] {-> MARK(numberSequence)} ANY{-PARTOF(number)};`

Comment: what I wanted to say: `[4,4]` is a valid construct. Maybe you want to add a -PARTOF(number) in order to avoid overlapping matches?

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for answering me. I am not sure what you mean by "how you tried to apply the last rule". I've used as test sentences the ones I have written on top of my question and the script was annotating both. Btw, I have tried to extend the rule as you suggested and indeed it is working as I wanted. Should you put it as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I had the impression that you already found the solution for your problem: the min/max quantifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an exemplary rule for annotating text positions if there are exactly four annotations of the type `number`:

```
ANY{-PARTOF(number)} @number[4,4] {-> MARK(numberSequence)} ANY{-PARTOF(number)};
```

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*